# Download ios 4.2.1 outside of itunes?

Tags: itunes, ipad

I am unable to download the 4.2.1 update for ipad from within itunes.  I am on a CDMA network, and the 700+MB update is too large to download in one session.  Each time the download times out I have to restart from the beginning.  Is there some hidden place where I can download the update package with a download manager?  I'm going nuts here.

Also, note to Apple: the "Resume" button in the download manager should be renamed "Start all over again, bwahahahah!".

Answer (score 1):

As usual, I have discovered my answer shortly after giving up on my search.  The direct download links can be found here:

http://www.macstories.net/news/breaking-ios-4-2-now-available-for-download/